# css - text with a light shadow color and foreground with darker color

Tags: html, css, colors

its just an esthetic problem, but the thing is I have a list of texts with random colors, but they're all light/bright colors (and must be), which makes them hard to read on white backgrounds. I set that color to the text shadow, and I want the text itself to have a darker, readable color, similar to the main light color

my problem is, if I set the text brightness or give it a black color with a lower alpha, it looks too greyish, and I want it to be more and more saturated the darker it is, so it keeps the main color more visible:

[image] or 
[image]

is there any css blender or formula I can implement that gives me one of those results?

Comment: Can you share how the html structure with classes looks like? I think it will depend on how we are able to manage your HTML/CSS and there is probably a solution

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve that by applying both css functions brightness(0.6) and contrast(200%). Those values can be changed, but I suggest changing the brightness only (for how dark you want the text), as that contrast value already gives a nice color to the darkened text

Answer (score 0):

i understand what your looking for but you cant really archive it efficiently with css alone i will suggest using sass `.scss` with the codes below:

```
$primary-color: #444;

//set text color function
@function set-text-color($color){
    @if (lightness($color) > 40){
        @retrun #000;
    }
    else{
        @retrun #fff;
    }
}

/*the above function will 
retrun black if the primary-color is light and 
return white if the primary color is dark */

body{
    background: $primary-color;
    color: set-text-color($primary-color);
}
```

where your primary-color is your basic text color. you can adjust the function to return  a color similar to what your using in a darker or lighter state.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I wanted it to be dynamic, as I generate many random colors. I still managed to achieve what I wanted by applying 2 css functions to my text: brightness(0.6) and contrast(200%), which gives me a darker yet vibrant color

Comment: @GustavoBerwanger excellent i didn't think of that, thought you wanted to change the colors on the fly and still keep the text visible. add your solution as an answer for future onlookers.